# Pandas add n number of new date rows to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a number of  months to the end of my dataframe.

What is the best way to append another six (or 12) months to such a dataframe using dates?

```
0    2013-07-31
1    2013-08-31
2    2013-09-30
3    2013-10-31
4    2013-11-30
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: I think you might want `pd.date_range`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2010-01-31', '2010-02-28'], 'x':[1,2]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
    date        x
0   2010-01-31  1
1   2010-02-28  2
```

Then

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start=df.date.iloc[-1], periods=6, freq='M', closed='right')}))

    date        x
0   2010-01-31  1.0
1   2010-02-28  2.0
0   2010-03-31  NaN
1   2010-04-30  NaN
2   2010-05-31  NaN
3   2010-06-30  NaN
4   2010-07-31  NaN
```

Comment: need to create a monthly series chronologically.  Adding a number of new months to the df. thanks

Answer (score 0):

After looking into append and other loop sort of options I created this:

```
length = df.shape [ 0 ]
add = 12

start = df [ 'month' ].iloc [ 0 ]
count = int ( length + add )

dt = pd.date_range ( start, periods = count, freq = 'M' )
```

this is the dt I get.  It gives the proper ending month days.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2013-07-31', '2013-08-31', '2013-09-30', '2013-10-31',
           '2013-11-30', '2013-12-31', '2014-01-31', '2014-02-28',
           '2014-03-31', '2014-04-30', '2014-05-31', '2014-06-30'],
            dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

now I just have to change from the DatetimeIndex.

I hope this is good code.  Cheers.